# mongodb - how to aggregate/filter elements in different subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a doc looks like below:

```
{
"contents": [
    {
        "translationId": "MENU",
    },
    {
        "translationId": "PAGETITLE"
    }
],
"slides": [
    {
        "translationId": "SLIDE1",
        "imageUrl": "assets/img/room/1.jpg",
        "desc": {
            "translationId": "DESC",
        }
    },
    {
        "translationId": "SLIDE2",
        "imageUrl": "assets/img/aa/2.jpg"
    }
]}
```

I would like to aggregate against the translationId no matter in which subdocument the data is. My current query is like below which does not give me the expected result.

```
db.cursor.find({"contents.translationId": { $exists: true }},
{"contents.translationId":1,'slides.translationId':1,"slides.desc.translationId":1,'_id':0})
```

I expect result like below. Is there a good approach to retrieve such a result directly from mongodb query?

```
[
  {
    "translationId": "MENU"
  },
  {
    "translationId": "PAGETITLE"
  },
  {
    "translationId": "SLIDE1"
  },
  {
    "translationId": "SLIDE2"
  },
  {
    "translationId": "DESC"
  }
]
```

Additionally, I might not know in which element translationId might exists. In this case it resides in contents, slides and slides.desc but it might also be under some other elements. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the items are unqiue you can use the [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator in modern MongoDB releases 2.6 and over, as well as the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator for transaltion of just the required element from the other array:

```js
db.cursor.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "joined": { 
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$setUnion": [
                    "$contents",
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$slides",
                        "as": "slide",
                        "in": {
                            "translationId": "$$slide.translationId"
                        }
                    }},
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$slides",
                        "as": "slide",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$ifNull": [ "$$slide.desc.translationId", false] },
                                { "translationId": "$$slide.desc.translationId" },
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }}
               ]},
               [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

You also need `$setDifference` to filter out any `false` values returned where the "desc" field is not present.

It produces:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f13f444db9bc30de351c84"),
        "joined" : [
                {
                        "translationId" : "DESC"
                },
                {
                        "translationId" : "SLIDE2"
                },
                {
                        "translationId" : "SLIDE1"
                },
                {
                        "translationId" : "PAGETITLE"
                },
                {
                        "translationId" : "MENU"
                }
        ]
}
```

Of course if you have no idea of the structure "at all", then you need a recursive function with mapReduce instead:

```js
db.cursor.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var tags = [];

        function walkObj(obj) {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
                if ( typeof(obj[key]) == "object" ) {
                    walkObj(obj[key]);
                } else if ( key == "translationId" ) {
                    tags.push({ "translationId": obj[key] })
                } 
            });
        }

        walkObj(this);
        emit(this._id,{ "joined": tags})            
    },
    function(){},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which gives basically the same output as before but of course does not need to be aware of the structure

Comment: I believe the recursive function approach is even simpler.

Comment: @komushi Sure, but the point is that if you have "some idea" of the structure it is not going to be the most "efficient". So you should really only "walk" the object if it truly is random and you could not possibly map all the field locations. Not only faster than a recursive search in general, but also as the aggregation framework is native coded operators and not interpreted JavaScript code then is it faster also. But use what you need to apply to your situation.